# Firebase analytics event app_remove not firing in cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

I have added a analytics cloud function on trigger of app_remove event but unfortunately that event is not firing at all other custom analytics events are working fine

Comment: Did you mark `app_remove` as a conversion event? See the first blue box on https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/analytics-events

Comment: Yeh i really missed to read that point I will mark event as conversion event and try again

Comment: Make sure your event is marked as a conversion